# Determine the total size of the cache

Tags: caching, hardware, cpu-architecture

Here is the problem:
A computer system has 32MB of main memory, and a set associative cache. Assume that every cache line holds 16 bytes of data. The tag field of the main memory address is ten bits wide. If the cache were direct mapped, then the size of the tag field would have been 7 bits. Using this information, find the set associativity of the cache (the number of lines per set). Determine the size and the number of comparators in the cache hardware. Also, determine the total size of the cache and express your answer in kilobytes. Assume that every cache line has 4 extra book-keeping bits in addition to tag and data.

So what I came up with is this:
8-way set associative, needs 8 comparators 10 bits each.

I'm stuck on figuring out the total size of the cache, because I'm not sure how many data bits there are and the equation I have seems to require that piece of information. Here's the equation:
(2^(index bits)) * [(associativity)(tag bits + valid bits + data size)]

So I'm guessing it would be:
2^11 * (8(10+(1+1+1+1)+data size))

So what exactly is the data size, assuming I got everything else correct?

Comment: I think you need to tag this as a 'homework' question.

Answer (score 1):

When they're asking for the cache size, they are asking for the sum of all the building blocks of the cache.

That would be

```
(# of sets) * associativity * blocksize
```

I'm not sure what is 2^11 ... But I don't think that's how you solve it.